# AWS RDS Postgres: How to see which query/process is using memory

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-aurora

Running a RDS Aurora Postgres cluster with two r6g.2xlarge instances that started fluctuating in memory usage around 6:50pm EST yesterday. Typically we are running with ~16gb headroom but it dips to ~5gb at ~10m intervals. At some points it dipped below the threshold that it needed to restart the instance. We rolled back any code changes that had happened during the day.

The instances are running postgres 12.12

How can I see which process/query is using this memory?

Comment: I don't think there is a particular good way to do that on RDS.  A query which uses a lot of memory is *probably* going to use a lot of time as well. So I would start with the slow queries.  Or if you get OOM errors, the log file should show you what query it was for.  If you get reaped by the OOM killer, though, it wouldn't.

Comment: Analyzing memory usage is hard enough with a regular installation. With a hosted database, you have no chance. Trial and error is all you can do.